# Product Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need versioning of my MVC applicaton.

How can i get product versioning of my application?

My Code:

```
VersionNumber = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Version`

If you want to see how its works, look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx